# apologise for or apologise about

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs, politeness

Recently I found out some forums asking if "apologise about" is or not correct, but none of them have clear response. Can someone explain if there is any difference between those two terms? It is important for an essay. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual preposition (other than 'to' to show who the apology is addressed to) chosen to follow **apologise** is **for**:

> I must apologize to Isobel for my lateness.
>
> Trains may be subject to delay – we apologize for any inconvenience
>   caused.
>
> She apologized profusely for having to leave at 3.30 p.m.

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/apologize)]

In these examples, one apologises for the deed / inaction / inconvenience or damage caused.

...................................

But sometimes, the apology is given to cover something or someone where the actual offence is not explicitly stated. 'About' is usually preferred in such (vaguer) cases.

> She's apologised about the incident.

(but *what* incident isn't specified)

[{Kiss FM](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22apologised+about%22&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&oq=%22apologised+about%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7510j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

> He had to apologise about that young girl Carly because he got it all
>   wrong.

(what had he been accusing her of [or claiming she had achieved?])

[[Sentencedict.com](https://sentencedict.com/apologise.html); ex 17]

> Cllr Allen, who has been a Tory councillor since 2004, apologised
>   about the picture, claiming he did not intend to cause offence.

(was it too revealing? amateurish? had he forgotten to bring it? sat on it and broken it?)

[[Daily Telegraph](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22apologised+about%22&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&oq=%22apologised+about%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7510j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)